# How to deal with Indic languages in web application?

Tags: internationalization

I am working on a web application (Spring MVC and Hibernate) which requires Indic language support with CRUD operation and I tried Google Translate and it is useless for my requirement. Then I tried [Quillpad](http://www.quillpad.in) and it has good features and i can easily type in most of the Indic (without being aware of local language typing) but if I save local language data to database it shows like this `???? ???? ???` (even while fetching the records ). Then I used [Google IME](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/index.html) and this is also the same as "Quillpad". Even if I executed a query which allows database to accept 'UTF-8', there is still no success.

My questions:

1. How can I save data typed in any indic language to the database?
2. Is Unicode required to save/fetch record(s) from the database?
3. Is there any other requirements to display that data on HTML pages?
4. Is their any free API which help me with these?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some code? How do you move the data between Quillpad (or Google IME) to your DB query?

Comment: Your question is extremely broad and you haven't mentioned any technology you are using. It's a bit hard to answer in its current form.

Comment: @Paweł Dyda I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could provide more context, but let's try to stay high level then.

1. No matter if it's Indic, or any other language supported by Unicode, there is nothing special to be done. Provided that you are using any modern programming language like Java or C#. You may use [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) if you like.
2. Unicode is required or at least recommended (I don't think you want to use [ISCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Script_Code_for_Information_Interchange)) on database fields. Depending on the database you may want to set character encoding to have `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` store Unicode characters or simply use `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`.
3. There are many requirements that have to be met in order to display Indic characters in HTML. First, you need to have Unicode data source. Then you have to make sure that valid Unicode-family encoding is set on your page (i.e. `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. Also, the server should return the data with valid `Content-type` header (i.e. `Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`) and the data itself must be encoded in declared encoding. Finally, the font you use to display the text must support Indic-specific Unicode code points (you'll probably see many squares or question marks otherwise).
4. There is gazillion of free libraries to support you on your journey. However, usually built-in platform routines will suffice. I can't recommend anything, since you keep your technology stack top secret...

Comment: i am using Java (Spring MVC and Hibernate) Technology, is it possible to give any example so that it help me a lot...?

Answer (score 0):

I got some answer for above questions

for 1) What ever the database first we should convert / create the schema which accept UTF-8 characters, even we can do this for table Or field

OR

while connecting our program to database @ URL part we should specify like this  "characterEncoding=utf8"

```
ex: url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name?characterEncoding=utf8
```

for 2) I think Not necessary but if you able to do with Unicode it is for better

for 3) keep this on head part

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

---

for  4) better to look at this once [see this](http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/tools-for-typing-in-indian-languages-65925.html)

And if any one want translator plugin "Google Translator" is good for short text, it convert  text to selected language with more accuracy.

If you want to type in different " Local Language " and using google chrome then install "[this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab?hl=en)" (It wont work offline), If you want offline and using windows " Operating system "  then use "[this](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/)"

If you are using Linux flavored OS then use "ibus input method " it is good

so far i got this much if any thing is present please let me know.